# NodeJS console.log() in controller functions not working

Tags: node.js, backend, console.log

the functions within my controllers (NodeJS backend) are executing fine, but the console.log() apparently doesn't log into the terminal.

it goes the same for all functions in various controllers.

could anyone advice me some possibilities of where might go wrong ? or how i could debug this ?

Comment: Paste the code you tried here, so we can help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways to debug:

1. First, you should make sure your process doesn't exit before reaching the console logs.
2. You can use try and catch to display any error may happen.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing this strange behaviour of **node.js**  but actually the reason behind this strange behaviour was **nodemon**. then i just started my server without nodemon and it worked fine. i got my console logs.